# CENTOS / RHEL 7 - Setting SMBv2 for CIFS transfer

Tags: centos7, samba, rhel7, cifs

Hello my company recently switched from SMBv1 to SMBv2 on our Windows Servers as a result our CIFS mounts stopped working. I have searched the internet for a solution but I haven't found one that works....

I have tried adding the following values to the global section of the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file:

`server max protocol = SMB2` <-- It didn't work

`max protocol = SMB2` <-- It didn't work

`min protocol = SMB2` <-- It didn't work

`protocol = SMB2` <-- It didn't work

All of the above option after attempting to restart the samba service returned the following error:

> Failed to restart smb.service: Unit not found.

On the CIFS command I tried to specify vers=2.0 and that doesn't work either....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I found out by issuing the following command through PowerShell on my Windows server that I needed to be using version 3.0 which I didn't realize

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-SmbConnection


ServerName   ShareName    UserName   Credential Dialect NumOpens

----------   ---------    --------   ---------- ------- --------

WINP00092343 Backup       US\root    US\root    3.02    1
```

Using these details I updated my Linux mount command in fstab to:

```
//10.220.034.01/Backup /mnt/WINP00092343 cifs auto,domain=WINP00092343,username=CIFSuser,password=*************,vers=3.0 0 0
```

Note the ",3.0" in the above command, I hope this helps people out.